# how to put the right uppercase for insert data

Tags: php, mysql

When i put the upper at the value for %s it come out with the sql syntax error...which part i may get wrong and how to fix it..can some please correct me because it seem new for newbie like me

```
$insertSQL = sprintf('INSERT INTO kontrak (ID, NAME, T_LAHIR, Country) VALUES (%s,(UPPER(%s)), %s, %s)',

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], 'int'),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Nama'], 'text'),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Tarikhlahir'], 'date'),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Country'], 'text'));


You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''')), '1983-12-15','42151566'(LONDON' at line 1
```

Comment: thanks x bone...i still learning abaout this stackoverflow website

Comment: what does `GetSQLValueString()` do?

Comment: You should be passing variables in place of %s in sprintf but you are not doing that. Please check syntax.

Comment: RPM-that GetSQLValueString() i take from dreamweaver cs6 wizard for insert...

Comment: Lenin- how i must pass the variables in sprintf...because i'm using dreamweaver insert wizard...and not my own script

Comment: for u guys i'm sorry because in this php n mysql i'am new and in certain word i may understand...so please help me to understand it, because in google i still not understand from certain website

Comment: Change UPPER('%s') to UPPER(%s), you don't use quotes with parameters in this way. It's probably causing the error.

Comment: I have edited Wing Lian's answer @NixshamBMohamad see that for understanding. Also, try to get rid of DreamWeaver for programming in PHP. Adopt a code friendly IDE(NetBeans, Sublime Text 2). To know more about codefriendly IDEs you can watch tutorials on [nettuts.com](http://nettuts.com)

Comment: Do an `echo $insertSQL;` and post its results here.

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) or [ucwords()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), (If you want to capitalize only first character) in the second part of `sprintf()` function.

In this way you have more control over the inserted records, as php provides more string formatting functions then mysql.

Answer (score 1):

don't use upper there

```
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO kontrak (ID, NAME, BIRTH, COUNTRY) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",

                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Id'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Birth'], "date")),
                   strtoupper(GetSQLValueString($_POST['Country'], "text")));
```

Comment: wing lian thank you very much...for your help u all of u guys...^_^

Comment: The actual problem causing the syntax error was the use of single quotes in the query string in UPPER('%s'), which causes a syntax error because it should be UPPER(%s). This should make even the original query work fine, without the need to use PHP's strtoupper the way it is used in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
UPPER('%s')
```

to:

```
UPPER(%s)
```

You're already using %s parameters here and the single quotes are causing a syntax error.